# How to update a CheckedListItem using WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

One of my classes

```
public class CheckedListItem<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
```

has the method

```
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return isChecked; }
        set
        {
            isChecked = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsChecked"));
            }
        }
    }
```

My XAML looks like

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Employee}" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Content="{Binding Path=Item.Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

My employee.cs file

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I cant figure out how I can write back to the database when a item is checked or unchecked.

I would appreciate any help and would be more than happy to post the entire code for any files you need to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get what you want by adding TwoWay for mode and PropertyChanged on UpdateSourceTrigger.

Final XAML will then be:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Employee}" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Content="{Binding Path=Item.Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

EDIT:
By the way, I think you might be setting your ItemsSource incorrectly. I'm sure what you want is to bind that listbox to a collection of Employees?

Something like:

```
    public ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees 
    {
        get { return _employees; }
        set
        {
           _employees = value;
           if (PropertyChanged != null)
              {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Employees"));
            }
        }
  }
```

I misunderstood the question so here comes second edit:

Your class files would instead look like this:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<MutableKeyValuePair<Employee, bool>> _employees;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Employees = new ObservableCollection<MutableKeyValuePair<Employee, bool>>
        {
            new MutableKeyValuePair<Employee, bool>(new Employee("Joakim"), false),
            new MutableKeyValuePair<Employee, bool>(new Employee("SoftwareIsFun"), false),
        };
    }

    public ObservableCollection<MutableKeyValuePair<Employee, bool>> Employees
    {
        get { return _employees; }
        set
        {
            _employees = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Employees));
        }
    }

    public void UpdateDatabase()
    {
        foreach (var employee in Employees)
        {
            if (employee.Value)
            {
                //DATABASE LOGIC HERE
            }
        }
    }
}

public class MutableKeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>
{
    public TKey Key { get; set; }
    public TValue Value { get; set; }

    public MutableKeyValuePair()
    {

    }

    public MutableKeyValuePair(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        Key = key;
        Value = value;
    }
}

public class Employee
{

    public Employee(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

XAML:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Key.Name}"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Value}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. How will the TwoWay update the database record? I have Code in my Code-Behind file that performs an SQL Query and it checks the box if the field in the table is 1 (or unchecks if the field is 0). Based on your response, it appears i did something wrong

Comment: @softwareisfun Sorry mate, I misunderstood your question. I thought you had trouble updating the IsChecked property.
I will update my answer with a approach you could use!

Comment: @softwareisfun Please let me know if my final edit helps you with what you are looking for by marking it as an answer :)

Comment: I changed my XAML to what you had using DataGrid and now I have a ton of errors like "False is an unexpected token causing the XML to be invalid"

Comment: I think i asked the wrong question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36793689/how-can-i-bind-an-sql-query-to-a-datagrid I reposted it