# How can I bind an SQL Query to a DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

```
    <DataGrid Name="getEmployees" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn />
            <DataGridTextColumn />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

This is my DataGrid

Here is my CodeBehind

```
    public ViewMyProxy()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
        FillDataGrid();
    }

    private void FillDataGrid()
    {

        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabase"].ConnectionString;
        string CmdString = string.Empty;
        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            CmdString = "SELECT proxyFor, enabled FROM accesscontrol WHERE currentlyLoggedOnUser = '" + Environment.UserName + "'";
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(CmdString, con);
            OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("Employee");
            sda.Fill(dt);
            getEmployees.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
        }
    }
```

My question

1. Is there a way to load the SQL query and bind it directly with the DataGrid?
2. The enabled column is a numeric field (0 = false and 1 = true), can we bind that to a DataGridCheckBoxColumn? Basically when the user unchecks a box, i want to update the table as quickly as possible.

Using the Code-behind, when my WPF loads, I end up with 3 columns instead of 2. I want the 1st column to be the Checkbox (enabled from SQL query) and the proxyFor is a String that I want in the 2nd Column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `DataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns` to `False`, to prevent it from automatically generating the columns. Then you need to explicitly bind the columns that you defined yourself. [`DataGridCheckBoxColumn`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcheckboxcolumn_properties(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`DataGridTextColumn`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtextcolumn_properties(v=vs.110).aspx) both have other properties you can set as well, to further customize what you see in the grid.

```
<DataGrid 
    Name="getEmployees" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn 
            Binding="{Binding enabled}"
            Header="Enabled"
            />
        <DataGridTextColumn 
            Binding="{Binding proxyFor}"
            Header="Proxy For"
            />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

If the checkbox column doesn't work the way you want, you could try writing a [value converter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) to convert between your integer and a boolean.

XAML (partial):

```
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn 
            xmlns:myconv="clr-namespace:MyProject.Converters"
            Binding="{Binding enabled, Converter={myconv:IntToBool}}"
            />
```

C#

```
namespace MyProject.Converters
{
    public class IntToBool : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
    {
        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) => this;

        public virtual object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return ((int)value) != 0;
        }

        public virtual object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return ((bool)value) ? 1 : 0;
        }
    }
}
```

If that doesn't work, you'll need to use a [`DataGridTemplateColumn`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn(v=vs.110).aspx) instead, which will give you a lot more power to control what the column looks like and how it works.

In answer to your first question, "Is there a way to load the SQL query and bind it directly with the DataGrid?", I'm not sure exactly what that means: Are you asking if you can assign a SQL string to some property of `DataGrid` and have it execute the query and populate itself? No. You could write an attached property to do that, if you really wanted to. That might be fun.

Another point, which you didn't ask about but ought to be mentioned:

```
CmdString = "SELECT proxyFor, enabled FROM accesscontrol WHERE currentlyLoggedOnUser = '" 
    + Environment.UserName + "'";
```

If you already know that's bad practice and you're planning to replace it once you get the code working, then you don't need to hear this, but in case that's not so, you should really make an absolute habit of using parameters:

```
CmdString = "SELECT proxyFor, enabled FROM accesscontrol WHERE "
    + "currentlyLoggedOnUser = @userName";

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(CmdString, con);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("userName", Environment.UserName);
```

What if [somebody has a single quote in his user name](https://serverfault.com/a/604554/164638)? It can happen. And if you use simple concatenation of SQL strings in externally-facing code, you're allowing anybody on Earth to run arbitrary SQL in your database.

Why do you have `ItemsSource="{Binding}"` in the XAML? That will bind the DataGrid's DataContext to ItemsSource. If your view has a viewmodel, that DataContext should be the viewmodel; otherwise, it's probably null. And you're assigning something else in code behind anyhow.

Comment: I dont know why I had it there. Someone told me to put it there and the XAML included ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=accesscontrol}"

Comment: @softwareisfun Well, ordinarily you'd put the query results in an `ObservableCollection` on your view model and you would bind it like that: `ItemsSource="{Binding WhateverICalledMyResultsCollection}"`. And that's recommended, but I figured we didn't need to go there until you've got the grid working this way.

Comment: How would we update the record if we wanted to change the state of the checkbox from Enabled to Disabled?

Comment: @softwareisfun You mean from the viewmodel or from codebehind? For that, you'd either (a) keep a reference to the DataTable around and navigate it, or (b) instead of using a DataTable, use an ObservableCollection of a POCO class that has the same two fields as the DB records and implements INotifyPropertyChanged. You'd read the DB, create a new POCO class instance for each record, then when you want to change field values you'd do that through the instances in the ObservableCollection. To save back to DB you'd have to write a loop to go through the POCO things.

Comment: Isnt POCO for SQLServer. I am using MS Access. I looked on the Internet for POCO Generator and POCO and found many articles about SQL SERVER.

Comment: which one is easier to implement? (a or b)

Comment: @softwareisfun Access, SQL Server -- all the same. The point of POCO is it doesn't make any difference where the data originally came from. Write a class, create a new instance of the class, assign values to its properties from... anywhere. If you're pulling those values from a DataTable, doesn't matter where the DataTable's stuff originally came from (actually doesn't much matter to the DataTable either at that point).

Comment: @softwareisfun I'd take a whack at the DataTable version first. I bet you can get it working pretty quick. *If* this is a serious application you'll be maintaining for a while, though, the POCO/vm approach is really the only choice: Far easier to maintain and extend. That's what I'd do from the get-go for anything, but I've done it so many times I can do it in my sleep. I build everything around viewmodels from the first line of code I write, which I think may not be the case with your thing here.

Comment: @softwareisfun "POCO" == "Plain Old C# Objects". It means regular classes that aren't tied to anybody's mess of dependencies. Except `INotifyPropertyChanged` is a dependency, of course, so I'm abusing the term slightly.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll look into DataTable version first. If the application requirements grow then I may switch to POCO. So I create a object within the class scope called DataTable, how would I keep track of what cells changed or push those changes to the database?

Comment: @softwareisfun Three options: (a) [DataTable.RowChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.rowchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) and [DataTable.ColumnChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.columnchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) events; (b) make a clone of the DataTable and compare the two when user clicks Save or application exits. (c) Bite the bullet and POCO it, with a dirty flag on the POCO class.